# Initializing a string array

Tags: c++

I try to initialize a string array with std::cin but I can not
this is my code :

```
string *words[6];

for (int i=0 ; i<6;i++){    
    cin >> words[i];    //error
}
```

can anybody help me!!

Comment: Typo: `string *words[6]; => string words[6];`

Comment: Why not `std::array<std::string,6> words;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create them dynamically:

```
string words[6];    //notice I deleted '*' here
for (int i=0 ; i<6;i++){
    cin >>words[i];
}
```

What you've created is array of pointers, in which every pointer must be initalized with `new` before you can use it and deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

you have an array of pointers to `std::string`, but for your code to work you need an array of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
std::string words[6][6];

for (int y=0; y<6; ++y)
  for (int x=0; x<6; ++x){
    cin >> words[x][y];
}
```

Comment: "a string array 2d?"

Comment: @RiadBaghbanli Most likely the user is confusing a `char[][]` and a `std::string[]`